# R: Filter a list of dataframes based on indivual dataframe's column value

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to filter a list of dataframes based on their column values. Here's a smaller example of my actual dataframe:

```
DF <- data.frame(Company=c('Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Alpha', 'Beta', 'Beta', 'Gamma', 'Gamma'),
              Location=c('NY', 'NY', 'CHI', 'LA', 'CHI','LA', 'LA' ),
              ID=c('1234', '1234', '1234', '5678', '5678', '2468', '2468'),
              Charge=c(25,25,51, 60,60, 15, 15))
```

I used a split funtion to create a list of dataframes based on Company

```
List<- DF %>% base::split(., .$Company)
```

I want to filter the dataframes in the list based on the Charge column. I only want to keep the dataframes where the sum of the Charge column is greater than or equal to 100. I used this code:

```
Filtered_List <- sapply(List, function(x) sum( x$Charge )>=100)
```

However, this code is not filtering, it appears to just be assinging "TRUE/FALSE" values instead. I'm thinking the issue is down to how I am using the apply function but I could use some input. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your `sapply()` to index into the list:

```
Filtered_List <- List[sapply(List, \(x) sum(x$Charge) >= 100)]
```

Result:

```
$Alpha
  Company Location   ID Charge
1   Alpha       NY 1234     25
2   Alpha       NY 1234     25
3   Alpha      CHI 1234     51

$Beta
  Company Location   ID Charge
4    Beta       LA 5678     60
5    Beta      CHI 5678     60
```